# JAWS screen reader handles unchecked radio button as 'partially checked'

Tags: html, radio-button, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am using JAWS version 15 to test my page on Google Chrome that contains a set of related radio buttons, none of which are checked initially.

I expect JAWS to read an unchecked radio button as "radio button not checked", but to my surprise it reads any radio button as "radio button partially checked".

I created a simple test page that has only relevant HTML in it to make sure nothing else is affecting this behaviour, but it still reads "radio button partially checked".

Is there anything that I am missing? How can I instruct JAWS to read "radio button NOT checked"?

I tried adding aria-checked="false", however this didn't help.

Below is a simple snippet I am using to test the behaviour:

```
<form>
  <p>Question</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a1" />answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a2" />answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a3" />answer3
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried JAWS against IE or Firefox in addition to Chrome? My understanding is that JAWS tends to work best against IE so you may get best results there; Chrome accessibility support is relatively newer.

Comment: Nope, I haven't tried on IE... Thanks for the idea, I  will give it a go!

Comment: I ran into this same issue with "partially checked" being read by JAWS with Chrome.  Any chance you ever figure out how to suppress it?  I think it's a JAWS issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be fixed in JAWS 16. 
If you can you should upgrade to JAWS 16.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem with JAWS 16 in Chrome for me.  It works fine in IE and Firefox.  I also tried JAWS 14 since I still had it installed.  Again, it worked fine in IE and FF but not in Chrome.

I hear different things depending on whether I TAB to the radio group or if I use JAWS' virtual cursor.

If I TAB to the radio, I hear "radio button foo, checked, not checked".  So it's a bit confused on whether it's checked or not since it tells me both.

If I use the down arrow to move the virtual cursor, JAWS will say "radio button foo, not checked, partially checked".

It's a bug with Chrome.